# Page blinks/flickers on autosave (only on CSS file)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just switched from Atom to VsCode and I am having this problem.

I am writing a quiz test since I am practicing with JS and I found out that every time I type something in CSS (character, space), I see for a very brief moment the content of the web page in the HTML's default position (so, left aligned).

It's very annoying. This happens only with CSS, not with HTML or JS.

I looked through questions here but none of them had the exact problem I have, at least from what I saw.

Here I added some photos. The first one is ok, how it should be, but in the second one, as I was typing some random spaces, it quickly lost all the styling.

[image: First image - normal behavior]

[image: Second image - weird behavior].

For that 1000th of a second the CSS stops working and it does that everytime I press a keyword button. Makes you dizzy.

Here the code, maybe I did something wrong (?)

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.title ~ h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.questions {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="quizCont">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Welcome to the most exciting quiz</h1>
      <h3>Are you ready to test your abilities?</h3>
    </div>
      <h3>Here we go!</h3>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="questions">

      <div class="question1">
        <h3>1. What is the capital of the United States?</h3>
        <p>a. New York</p>
        <p class="quest1">b. Washington D.C.</p>
        <p>c. Texas</p>
      </div><br><br>

      <div class="question2">
        <h3>2. When was Google invented?</h3>
        <p>a. 1980</p>
        <p>b. 2000</p>
        <p class="quest2">c. 1996</p>
      </div><br><br>

      <div class="question3">
        <h3>3. What was the year the man walked on the Moon?</h3>
        <p class="quest3">a. 1969</p>
        <p>b. 1920</p>
        <p>c. 2009</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<script src="main.js">


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be the VS code extension you are using.  Perhaps try a different code highlighting extension?  It doesn't happen for me.

Comment: you mean the syntax theme? sorry didn't understand

Comment: You're using VS code, if I understand correctly.  VS Code has extensions, like "html css support" and "intelliSense for CSS".  If you're using an extension for CSS support, try a different one.  If you're not using an extension for CSS support, try using one.  Extension marketplace is the (on my version) last icon on the left menu; it looks like 4 squares with one detached.

Comment: Do you mean the page you are working on flickers (E.g. a separate browser window, perhaps flickering as it reloads the page), or the IDE displaying the code?

Comment: Sorry, the web page.

Comment: @Jason I'll try to do that, Thanks!

Comment: That just sounds like it's refreshing to show you the latest version of the CSS file, I'm not sure if that's really a problem (You could turn off refresh on save, but that just turns off the feature completely as well as the flicker side effect)

Comment: My misunderstanding; I thought the problem was in your IDE, but you just said its in the web page.  I don't think I understand your question.  If you're seeing an issue in a web page, is it in a browser?

Comment: I'll try recording the screen so you can have a better idea

Comment: From what it sounds like to me, you are using the "Live Server" extension and probably have autosave set up so it saves after you type. The auto save would cause "Live Server" to automatically refresh the browser to show your most up to date assets. If the full CSS file isn't valid CSS then this can break your webpage and show without styles.

Comment: @DBS I updated the question with some photos, sorry can't upload videos on YTB right now. Hope it make the problem clearer

Comment: @Chris how could I know if it isn't valid? I mean, everything looks ok to me :))